# how to store a slice of byte slices?

Tags: go

I would like to understand how to store several byte slices separately in a slice. As hopefully illustrated below, I want the storage struct to store the result of the compressed result of n found in buf.

```
type storage struct 
{
    compressed []byte 
}       

func (s* storage) compress(n []byte) {
      var buf bytes.Buffer
      w := gzip.NewWriter(&buf)
      w.Write(n)
      w.Close()
      store := buf.Bytes()
      s.compressed = append(s.compressed, store)
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your code `compressed` is a slice of bytes. If you want to store slices of bytes you need a slice of slices of bytes. So change the type of `compressed` to `[][]byte`

Comment: Otherwise, if it should all be appended to the same slice, use `s.compressed = append(s.compressed, store...)`. Note the ellipsis after the last argument. This 'unpacks' the `store` slice into a list of separate bytes, each being a separate argument to `append`.

Comment: thank you. Nice to know. I thought I actually tried this, but I will try again:)

Comment: In simple words, in golang if you need to store an array of byte arrays, the declaration you need is var data [][]bytes